# Difference between "eq" and "=~/^string\b/i" in Perl

Tags: perl

What is the difference between following two when comparing string values in Perl

```
if ($delta eq "name")
```

Vs

```
if ($delta =~ /^name\b/i)
```

I am trying to compare two string values with "name" being read off the array indices.

Thanks

Comment: just use not only english language in your strings.
see two examples: `perl -e 'print q(dif) if q(∂ƒ) eq q(∂ƒ)'` and `perl -e 'print q(dif) if q(∂ƒ) =~ /^∂ƒ\b/i'`

Answer (score 3):

the `eq` is string equality. So it tests the string on the left matches the string on the right.

the '=~' is binding operator. It tests the string on the left agsinst the regex patter on the right.

More information can be found in the perldoc with these links [Equality Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) and [Binding Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators)

A short summary of each

**Binding operator**

> Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match. Certain operations search or modify the string $_ by default. This operator makes that kind of operation work on some other string. The right argument is a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration. The left argument is what is supposed to be searched, substituted, or transliterated instead of the default $_.

**Equality Operator**

> Binary "eq" returns true if the left argument is stringwise equal to the right argument.

To put this into context. your first statement will only be matched if value of $delta is "name" only (must be all lower case). the second example, will match if the value of $delta if starts with "name" regardless of the case.

if $delta was "name" - this would match in statement 1 and statement 2

if $delta was "NAME" - this would not match in statement 1 but would match in statement2

if $delta was "name of this person" - this would not match in statement 1 but would match in statement2

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not a regex, and is case-sensitive, it's just try to match the full string *as-is*.

The second one, is a regex ans is case-insensitive and can match just the first word of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The first one matches only if the variable $delta contains exactly the secuence `name`.

The second one is more *permissive*. It only need the secuence `name` at the start of the string followed by a word boundary to be successful. It also does not care if the secuence is `name` or `NAME` or `NaMe`, etc...